# Find the Composite for $(f\circ g) (x)$ where $ f(x)= 2x^2 + \frac{4}{x}, g(x)= \frac{1}{1+x}$

Tags: calculus

Find the Composite for  $(f\circ g) (x)$, where $f(x) =  2x^2 + \dfrac{4}{x}$, and $g(x)= \dfrac{1}{1+x}$

I got $4x^3+16x-\dfrac{4}{x+1}$.

Comment: What is $f$?   I can't discern the meaning of your question.  Please edit it and clarify.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that $$f(x) = 2x^2 + \frac 4x \;\text{ and }\;g(x) = \frac 1{1+x},$$ then

then remembering that $(f\circ g)(x) = f(g(x))$, we simply replace *every occurrence of $\color{blue}{x}$* in $f(x)$ with $g(x) =\color{blue}{\dfrac 1{1+x}}$
$$\begin{align} (f\circ g)(x) = f(g(x)) 
& = 2\color{blue}{\left(\frac 1{1+x}\right)}^2 + \frac 4{\color{blue}{\left(\dfrac 1{1+x}\right)}}\\ \\
& = \frac 2{(1+x)^2}+ 4(1+x)\\ \\
& = \frac{2+4(1+x)^3}{(1+x)^2}
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

To find the composite, it's good to note that $(fog)(x)=(f(g(x))$  With this said,  when you plug in $g(x)$ into $f(x)$ you get $2(\frac{1}{1+x})^2+\frac{4}{\frac{1}{1+x}}$.  The rest from there is simplification, which I think is different from your answer.  I get $4(x+1)+\frac{2}{(x+1)^2}$.  If you show us the steps to how you got to your answer, perhaps we could show you where a mistake might've been?

Answer (score 0):

$$f\left(g\left(x\right)\right)=2g\left(x\right)^{2}+\frac{4}{g\left(x\right)}=2\left(1+x\right)^{-2}+4\left(1+x\right)=2\left(1+x\right)^{-2}\left[1+2\left(1+x\right)^{3}\right]$$